# Troubleshooting automating a file upload

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to automate a file upload using the `requests` module in `python3`.  The setup (that I do manually) that I'm trying to replicate is as follows:

1. I go to the website for my notes (`SUBMIT_URL` in the code).
2. I get redirected to my college's login (`LOGIN_URL` in the code).
3. I login to my account (using my username/password, imported from `credentials.py` as I don't particularly want to share it here).
4. I get redirected back to the submitting webpage. It has an area to drag and drop files to.  I drag a file there, then submit it.

This is the entire process, and I have most of it working.
The file-hosting service I want to log into is called `moodle`, and it doesn't really have an API for this, so I've been trying to do it "manually".  I'm confident the logging in is working, as `login_page_query.content` returns something that says "You logged in, but we couldn't redirect you for whatever reason".
The issue seems to be with `draft_query` below.

`draft_query` is trying to mimic the request that [chrome sends here](https://justpaste.it/14znj), which I try to do with `DRAFT_FILES_PAYLOAD`. `sesskey`,`client_id`, and `itemid` all seem to be dynamically generated server-side somehow, but I'm able to get things that seem reasonable from a regex search over `submit_page.content`.  This typically looks like [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24278890/) (all of it is on a single line by default, so that link by itself might not be the most useful).

So, while I'm not able to compare the `sesskey`/other data with chrome (as each time I load the page it seems to change), each time I run the python I get something that is formatted the same as chrome, and seems reasonable.

The current error I'm running into is with `draft_query`.  `draft_query.content` is

```
b'{"error":"A required parameter (sesskey) was missing","errorcode":"missingparam","stacktrace":null,"debuginfo":null,"reproductionlink":null}'
```

even though `draft_files_payload` is

```
<MultipartEncoder: (('sesskey', 'X6DD4DCAHC'), ('client_id', '58dc838805c18'), ('filepath', '/'), ('itemid', '288033100'))>
```

which clearly includes the `sesskey`.  As a sidenote, I used to have `draft_files_payload` just as a dictionary, but I was worried that the order might matter.  This hasn't helped at all though.

Also of note is that for the query Chrome does that I'm trying emulate (with `draft_files_query`), the Content-Type is

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

`requests` defaulted to something like `text/plain`, so I've tried setting this as a header.  I can't tell if it's worked/had a positive impact though.

I'm not sure how specifically anyone can help me, as I can't really divulge the credentials needed to work on this hands-on.  Can anyone sugest general strategies/troubleshooting things I can do?  I really have very little idea what I'm doing, and got the far via extensive help yesterday (although now I feel comfortable enough with things that I feel like I could replicate what I have below).

To summarize:

**Current Error:**

`draft_query` is unsuccessful in replicating [this](https://justpaste.it/14znj) query, even though it appears I have the correct data/formatting.

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder
import http.client
from credentials import CREDENTIALS
import re
http.client.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'

# Regex patterns here
SESS_KEY_RE = re.compile(r"\"sesskey\":\"(\w*)\"")
ITEM_ID_RE = re.compile(r"\"itemid\":(\d*),")
AUTHOR_RE = re.compile(r"\"author\":\"([^\"]+)\"")
CTX_RE = re.compile(r";ctx_id=(\d+)&amp;")
CLIENT_ID_RE = re.compile(r"\"client_id\":\"(\w*)\"")
##

LOGIN_URL = 'https://weblogin.reed.edu/'
SUBMIT_URL = 'https://moodle.reed.edu/mod/data/edit.php?d=485'
DRAFT_FILES_URL = 'https://moodle.reed.edu/repository/draftfiles_ajax.php?action=list'
UPLOAD_URL = 'https://moodle.reed.edu/repository/repository_ajax.php?action=upload'
TITLE = r"MATH 389 3-20-17.pdf"
FILENAME = r"/home/mark/classes/moodle-notetaking-uploader/MATH 389 3-20-17.pdf"


# repo_id 4 seems to correspond with "upload a file", look at "sortorder":4
with open(FILENAME, 'rb') as f:
    s = requests.Session()
    s.get(SUBMIT_URL)
    # Removing above breaks this, not sure why
    login_page_query = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=CREDENTIALS)
    submit_page = s.get(SUBMIT_URL)
    text = l.content.decode()
    sess_key = SESS_KEY_RE.search(text).group(1)
    item_id = ITEM_ID_RE.search(text).group(1)
    author = AUTHOR_RE.search(text).group(1)
    ctx_id = CTX_RE.search(text).group(1)
    client_id = CLIENT_ID_RE.search(text).group(1)
    draft_header = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    draft_files_payload = MultipartEncoder(fields = (("sesskey", sess_key), ("client_id", client_id),
                           ("filepath", "/"), ("itemid", item_id)))
    file_payload = {"file": ("repo_upload_file", f, "application/pdf")}
    data_payload = {"sesskey": sess_key, "repo_id": "4", "itemid": item_id,
                    "author": author, "savepath": "/", "title": TITLE,
                    "ctx_id": ctx_id}
    draft_query = s.post(DRAFT_FILES_URL, data=draft_files_payload,headers = draft_header)
    file_query = s.post(UPLOAD_URL, files=file_payload, data=data_payload)
```

Comment: This is a Moodle error.  Your "sesskey" needs to be equivalent to the session key created when you log into Moodle.

Comment: @MartinGreenaway do you mean from the `login_page_query`?  [This](https://justpaste.it/saved/15325617/af2bd119) is the content of that, and [this](https://justpaste.it/150dq) is the headers returned from that request.  I can't seem to find any reference to `sesskey` in there.  A similar thing happens at the first `s.get(SUBMIT_URL)` (meaning no reference to `sesskey`), where the content is [this](https://justpaste.it/150e3) (this seems to just be the content of my college's login page, so I was redirected), and the headers are [here](https://justpaste.it/150eb).

Comment: @MartinGreenaway I've rechecked all the queries I've done and searched for `sess` in both their `.headers` and `.content`.  The only thing that contains them is `submit_page.content` (where I currently source the key from), and `draft_query.content` (the source of the error message I want to fix).  Where should I try to find the `sesskey` if not from `submit_page.content`?

Comment: You shouldn't.  You should be talking to your college's IT team and getting the session key from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it from a Multipart encoder to a simple dictionary.

draft_files_payload = {"sesskey":sess_key, "client_id":client_id, "filepath":"/", "itemid":item_id}